# Orbeon forms select default option text (select1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, orbeon

I'm using Orbeon forms select element (select1 to be precise), and I would need to change the default text *"Please select"* to a different one (e.g. *"Choose something"*), and it should always stay visible to the user - which is not happening currently.

What happens is when a user selects a "valid" option, moves out of the field, then opens the dropdown again, that "*Choose something*" option is not visible - and because of the requirements I have it should be visible. Quite a minor thing, but is causing me quite some troubles.

I thought that I could manipulate it all via JavaScript when the page loads, and also when the user clicks and opens the dropdown. I managed partially, but the problem is that Orbeon has some handlers which are always changing it back to "Please select", so "Choose something" is overriden..any ideas on how to achieve this, maybe something in Orbeon itself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For forms you create with Form Builder, Orbeon Forms uses the `dropdown-select1` XBL control. If you want to change "Please select" into "Choose something", the easiest thing would be for you to update the resources in the source of [that XBL control](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1/dropdown-select1.xbl).

Comment: Hi @avernet, thank you for the help, I've managed to solve it like that.